# How to write mongodb/nodejs query without setIntersection using aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, mern

I am using an old version on mongodb so I cannot use setIntersection.
I want to get intersection of two categories, sale and some other category.
In my case every product can have category_id and array of additional categories called category_ids which can contain id of sale category.
I have written next query but it doesn't work correctly

```
itemsAggregation.push({
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {
                        category_ids: {
                            $in: [params.category_id, '6273c1aabc7df41d6e3518da']
                        }
                    },
                    { category_id: params.category_id }
                ]
            }
        });
```

params.category_id is id of some category and the string is id of sale category

Version:

"mongodb": "^3.1.4",

Sample data

Single product:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61f12c5cd0b7910e766f0ba9"},"date_created":{"$date":"2022-01-26T11:11:24.809Z"},"date_updated":{"$date":"2022-05-04T14:30:06.128Z"},"images":[{"id":{"$oid":"62aae69fe3ba26163154f821"},"alt":"","position":99,"filename":"zarakaput.webp"},{"id":{"$oid":"62aae6a3e3ba26163154f822"},"alt":"","position":99,"filename":"kaput2.webp"}],"dimensions":{"length":0,"width":0,"height":0},"refund_approved_count":3,"refund_rejected_count":5,"name":"Kaput","description":"<p>- vrhunska kolica</p>\n<p>- bas bas dobra kolica</p>","meta_description":"muski kaput - meta","meta_title":"","tags":["test","AKCIJA","novo"],"attributes":[],"enabled":true,"discontinued":false,"slug":"kaput","sku":"123","code":"","tax_class":"","related_product_ids":[{"$oid":"61f11ef3c120b7097f8eb01c"},{"$oid":"61f143d36df8b5122d0fd0f1"},{"$oid":"61f11ef3c120b7097f8eb01c"}],"prices":[],"cost_price":0,"regular_price":100,"sale_price":90.5,"quantity_inc":1,"quantity_min":1,"weight":1,"stock_quantity":12,"position":null,"date_stock_expected":null,"date_sale_from":{"$date":"2022-05-26T12:31:40.223Z"},"date_sale_to":{"$date":"2022-05-27T22:00:00.000Z"},"stock_tracking":false,"stock_preorder":false,"stock_backorder":false,"category_id":{"$oid":"61f11ef3c120b7097f8eb014"},"category_ids":[{"$oid":"61f12bacd0b7910e766f0ba8"},{"$oid":"6239e69aae10f91ee7273ea0"}],"options":[{"id":{"$oid":"61f7fa379c70f8312a6571b5"},"name":"Boja","control":"select","required":true,"position":0,"values":[{"id":{"$oid":"6238424385670225ec539803"},"name":"Maximum Blue"},{"id":{"$oid":"628b771ee225162f4937ab7b"},"name":"Crvena"},{"id":{"$oid":"628b77d3e225162f4937ab84"},"name":"Zuta"}]},{"id":{"$oid":"62a1f322ca0a4fb7e00c886b"},"name":"Velicina","control":"select","required":true,"position":0,"values":[{"id":{"$oid":"62a1f33cca0a4fb7e00c886d"},"name":"22"},{"id":{"$oid":"62a1f33dca0a4fb7e00c886e"},"name":"23"}]},{"id":{"$oid":"62df943a48cf1fd956cb56bd"},"name":"New option","control":"select","required":true,"position":0,"values":[]}],"variants":[{"id":{"$oid":"62a9cea32adefd807f222262"},"sku":"","price":100,"stock_quantity":12,"weight":1,"options":[{"option_id":{"$oid":"61f7fa379c70f8312a6571b5"},"value_id":{"$oid":"628b771ee225162f4937ab7b"}},{"option_id":{"$oid":"62a1f322ca0a4fb7e00c886b"},"value_id":{"$oid":"62a1f33cca0a4fb7e00c886d"}}],"image":"62a9cea32adefd807f222262.webp"},{"id":{"$oid":"62a9cebe2adefd807f222263"},"sku":"","price":100,"stock_quantity":12,"weight":1,"options":[{"option_id":{"$oid":"61f7fa379c70f8312a6571b5"},"value_id":{"$oid":"6238424385670225ec539803"}},{"option_id":{"$oid":"62a1f322ca0a4fb7e00c886b"},"value_id":{"$oid":"62a1f33cca0a4fb7e00c886d"}}],"image":"62a9cebe2adefd807f222263.webp"}],"refund_count":8,"brand":"Testni brend"}
```

Single category (sale is also an category)

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"62d68dd8b7d9b8ca0f77d6e4"},"date_created":{"$date":"2022-07-19T10:56:24.279Z"},"date_updated":{"$date":"2022-07-19T10:57:03.019Z"},"image":"","name":"Sale","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_title":"","enabled":true,"sort":"","parent_id":null,"position":"7","code":"","name_translation":"Akcija","slug":"sale","totalProducts":10}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your mongodb version

Comment: I have added some data